# How to open a new page using SearchDelegate in Flutter

Tags: flutter, search, navigation

I am currently working on a search function in my flutter app. The search function works and shows the results in a ListTile. But I want to navigate to a specific page for each result shown in the ListTile. If I use the onTap function in the ListTile how can I match the results to their specific page?

Here is my list of Strings:

```
final testList = [
  'test 1',
  'test 2',
  'test 3',
  'test 4',
];
```

I use SearchDelegate to search for the results:

```
 @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = '';
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear)),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        },
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow, progress: transitionAnimation));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(child: Text(query),),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? testList
        : testList.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        tileColor: backGround,
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```